# Jquery Lavalamp current menu

Tags: jquery

I implemented the  Lavalamp menu in my website, and I wanted to do this: when the users click in some link in the menu, then the hover stays in that link.

The lavalamp effect is working.

The jquerycode I have is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#menutop").lavaLamp({
            fx: "backout",
            speed: 700,
           click: function(event, menuItem) {
                 return true;
               }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The html code for the menu is this:

```
<ul class="menu-top" id="menutop">
                <li class="current"><a href="index.php">Início</a></li>
                <li><a href="servidores.php">Servidores</a></li>
                <li><a href="pagamentos.php">Pagamentos</a></li>
                <li><a href="forum/">Fórum</a></li>
                <li><a href="sobre.php">Sobre</a></li>
</ul>
```

I think the solution is doing something with jquery that assigns the class current to the li with the href of the page we are viewing.

I don't know how to do this, but if you understood and know let me know xD

Thanks

ps: of course there are other pages in my website, but if there's not a li with the href of the page begin viewed, the current class will always be pointed in the li of the index.php

Answer (score 1):

@Afonso, This may be late but better late than never. It could help somebody else that reaches this page.

So you want the hover to stay under the li element of the page that you are currently on, right? For it we will change the plugin to accept the start position as a variable. Do it like this -

1. Set the options to have a start_position variable with default value 0.

   ```
   o = $.extend({ fx: "linear", speed: 500, start_position: 0, click: function(){} }, o || {});
   ```
2. Change plugin to set the curr element as shown

   ```
   curr = $("li.current", this)[o.start_position] || $($li[o.start_position]).addClass("current")[0];
   ```
3. Now in the javascript of the page you are at you can do:

   ```
   $("#navlinks").lavaLamp({
       fx: "backout",//optional
       speed: 700,
       start_position: 1,//When page is loaded hover will be under Servidores
       click: function(event, menuItem) {
           return true;//so that you navigate to the appropriate link under 'li'
       }
   });
   ```

I had used plugin version 0.1.0 to test this. And I did not do manual setting of the class 'current'.

So now you can manually set under which item you want the hover to be, irrespective of whether it links to the page being viewed or not.

Answer (score 1):

i m coding in php and it was a bit annoying to redefine the start_position evertime so i used php in my header to know what page i am on and set the current class accordingly :

//I get my current page name

```
<?php 
    $page = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    $page = substr($page, 1);
?>
```

// i compare the current page to my menu items

```
<ul class="arrowslide" id="1">
<li <?php if($page=="index.php")echo("class='current'");?>><a href="index.php">accueil</a></li>
<li <?php if($page=="club.php")echo("class='current'");?>><a href="club.php">le club</a></li>
<li <?php if($page=="equipe.php")echo("class='current'");?>><a href="equipe.php">l'equipe</a></li>
<li <?php if($page=="avion.php")echo("class='current'");?>><a href="avion.php">l'avion</a></li>
</ul>
```

Be carreful comparing your pages, if you are in subdirectory from your server, you ll need to substract another level or pu the entire address.
so either

```
$page = substr($page,2);
```

or

```
if($page=="directory/page.php")..
```

hope that helps those having the pb in the future!